# T-SQL - how to round DOWN to nearest .05

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005

The database I am using is SQL Server 2005. I am trying to round values DOWN to the nearest .05 (nickel).

So far I have:

`SELECT ROUND(numberToBeRounded / 5, 2) * 5`

which *almost* works - what I need is for the expression, when **numberToBeRounded** is **1.99**, to evaluate to **1.95**, not **2**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Specify a non-zero value for a third parameter to truncate instead of round:

```
SELECT ROUND(numberToBeRounded / 5, 2, 1) * 5
```

Note: Truncating rounds toward zero, rather than down, but that only makes a difference if you have negative values. To round down even for negative values you can use the `floor` function, but then you can't specify number of decimals so you need to multiply instead of dividing:

```
SELECT FLOOR(numberToBeRounded * 20) / 20
```

Comment: that works - the values should always be greater-than-or-equal-to 0 - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If your data type is `numeric` (ISO `decimal`) or `money, you can round towards zero quite easily, to any particular "unit", thus:

```
declare @value money = 123.3499
declare @unit  money = 0.05

select value                = value ,
       rounded_towards_zero = value - ( value % @unit )
from #foo
```

And it works regardless of the sign of the value itself, though the unit to which you're rounding should be positive.

```
 123.3499 ->  123.3000
-123.3499 -> -123.3000
```